# AFCompoundResponseSerializer JSON issue

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking's latest version in a project that connects to an API that returns both text responses and JSON responses so I use `AFCompoundResponseSerializer` to handle both response.

Request that return a JSON file are given to me as a `NSString` of the JSON response instead of an `NSDictionnary` that is normaly returned with AFJsonResponseSerializer, it looks like the `AFCompoundResponseSerializer` takes the response as plain text and doesn't send it to the `AFJsonResponseSerializer`

My code fore the CompoundSerializer is as follow:

```
        sharedSessionManager = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];
    sharedSessionManager.responseSerializer=[AFCompoundResponseSerializer compoundSerializerWithResponseSerializers:@[[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer], [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this happened:

The server returned JSON as `text/html` so the serializer sended it directly to `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` which returned a string instead of parsing the JSON.

**To fix this**, just add `text/html` to the JSON serializer's `acceptableContentTypes`